# What does the \afterassignment do in the following macro from the TikZ source code?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tex-core, sourcecode

The following macro is defined in the TikZ source code (specifically in `<tex installation directory>/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex`).

```
\def\tikz@scan@next@command{%
  \ifx\tikz@collected@onpath\pgfutil@empty%
  \else%
    \tikz@invoke@collected@onpath%
  \fi%
  \afterassignment\tikz@handle\let\pgf@let@token=%
}
```

What is the purpose of the `\afterassignment` in this context?

I'm not asking about `\afterassignmet` in general, though I sure won't mind a recap about how this construct works in general. But I'm particularly interested in what it means within the above macro in light of what the macro is supposed to do. A similar usage occurs many times in the TikZ source code. I hope that if I understand the example above, I'll understand it once and for all.

Comment: It simply swallows one token and executes `\tikz@handle`.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks. Could you please  explain in more detail how this works? Also, is there no simpler and more intuitive way to accomplish the same effect?

Comment: it allows you to see a following token `{` which you can not grab as `#1` , you could use `\futurelet` but no one has ever called `\futurelet` intuitive.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: How do you know that the following token will be an opening brace? Could you please explain in more detail how this works? Also, how would an equivalent `futurelet` expression look like?

Comment: no you don't know it is a following brace but using `\let` rather than `#1` means that if the following text is `{abc}` you just grab the `{` not the whole group (see my answer)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is similar to `\futurelet` in that it `\let` s the command name to the following token (ignoring one optional space) but unlike `\futurelet` it *consumes* the token

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\def\zza{\afterassignment\zzx\let\tmp=}
\def\zzb{\futurelet\tmp\zzx}
\def\zzc#1{\def\tmp{#1}\zzx}

\def\zzx{[tmp is \texttt{\meaning\tmp}] }


\begin{document}

A \zza xyz

B \zzb xyz

C \zzc xyz


A \zza {xyz

B \zzb {xyz}

C \zzc {xyz}

\end{document}
```

Note that the constructs A and B both use `\let` so "see" the following `{` whereas C which uses a macro argument "sees" the entire brace group.  A though removes the token from the input so `x` only appears once, and there needs to be no matching `}` for the `{`, however using `\zzb` with `\futurelet` leaves the token in the input stream (so `x` appears twice and you need a matching `}` as the `{` does start a group as well as being assigned to `\tmp`.

Comment: Why does it ignore only one optional space?

Comment: @EvanAad because that is how `\let` is defined, it ignores one optional space and one optional `=` but the `=` here is supplied already. If it ignored all white space you would not be able to let something to a space token.

Comment: I see. where did the `}` go in the output of the 2nd example designated with `B`?

Comment: @EvanAad it does `\let\tmp={` so `\tmp` is a left brace (just used with `\meaning` here) and the `{` is removed, that is the whole point of the construct.

Comment: But what happened to the *closing* brace?

Comment: @EvanAad If I want to define `\tmp` to be a left brace I can go `\let\tmp={` the `{` is then just the value of the assignment it never starts a group and there does not have to be a matching `}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63505/discussion-between-evan-aad-and-david-carlisle).

Answer (score 1):

I just want to complement David's answer with an explanation of the purpose this construct serves in the context of the macro listed in the original post.

When a

```
\path<body>
```

statement is encountered at the beginning of the input stream inside a TikZ environment, it is rewritten as

```
\tikz@scan@next@command <body>
```

`\tikz@scan@next@command` then assigns `<body>`'s first token to `\pgf@let@token`, and the last expression is rewritten as

```
\tikz@handle <body tail>
```

where `<body tail>` is obtained from `<body>` by deleting `<body>`'s first token.

`\tikz@handle` is a long switch statement that dispatches an appropriate handler based on the value of `\pgf@let@token`, so based on `<body>`'s first token.

Every handler gobbles down a chunk from the beginning of the input stream, processes it, and finally repositions `\tikz@scan@next@command` at the beginning of the reduced input stream:

```
\tikz@scan@next@command <reduced body>
```

where `<reduced body>` is what remains of `<body tail>` after the handler has bitten off a chunk from its head.

Thus `\tikz@scan@next@command` serves as a forward-moving cursor that is advanced by the handlers, and points to the current position in the input stream. The token this cursor is pointing at determines which handler will be dispatched next.

In these terms what the line

```
\afterassignment\tikz@handle\let\pgf@let@token=
```

does is removing the token at the cursor's position from the input stream, and assigning this token to `\pgf@let@token`.