# Define latex command in which argument is part of another command

Tags: macros, substitution

Is there a way to define a LaTeX command in which an argument forms part of a command that is expanded inside the text defined by the command?

For example, here's a MNWE (Minimal Non-Working Example--it doesn't work, and that's the basis of the question):

```
\newcommand{\firstExclamation}{Yesiree!}
\newcommand{\secondExclamation}{No way!}

\newcommand{\firstExplanation}{You are our favorite customer.}
\newcommand{\secondExplanation}{We're all out of that product.}

\newcommand{\usesMyCommands}[1]{I said, ``\#1Exclamation \#1Explanation"}
```

Then `\usesMyCommands{first}` should expand into "Yesiree! You are our favorite customer.", while `\usesMyCommands{second}` should expand into "No way! We're all out of that product."

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247956/how-to-define-a-command-that-defines-another-command) and its answer seem very relevant, as does [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/259287/how-to-define-a-newcommand-that-expands-into-another-newcommand), but after some experimentation, I have not figured out how to apply their lessons to my case.  These questions are about how to define a command inside a command, and I want to *use* a command inside a command.  Maybe I'm just not seeing it, though--maybe the answer is there in those answers, and I'm not realizing it.

I am sure that there is a way to do this is in raw TeX.  I'm hoping not to have to descend into the TeX swamp.  I respect those who routinely do so.  I have also looked at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65462/plain-tex-theory-afterassignment), [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385420/what-does-the-afterassignment-do-in-the-following-macro-from-the-tikz-source-co), and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9718/defining-commands-abbreviations-that-contain-numbers), but hope that I do not have to understand them. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\firstExclamation}{Yesiree!}
\newcommand{\secondExclamation}{No way!}

\newcommand{\firstExplanation}{You are our favorite customer.}
\newcommand{\secondExplanation}{We're all out of that product.}

\newcommand{\usesMyCommands}[1]{I said, ``\csname #1Exclamation\endcsname\ \csname#1Explanation\endcsname"}
\usesMyCommands{first}, \usesMyCommands{second}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks--that's great!  This is going to be extremely helpful.  I had tried messing around with `\csname` and `\endcsname`, but I didn't know what I was doing.  Among other things, I put a backslash in front of `#1`.  (For anyone who comes to this page without knowing what `\*csname` do [I didn't], [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39402/11250) gives a succinct statement of their use in Ulrike's answer here, and other answers to that question describe other uses.)