# A database for a Psalter

Tags: datatool, database

I would like to create a book (to be exact a psalter). Basically it is a database issue. I have on one hand a tex document (to be exact currently it's still a word document) with all the psalms and on the other the book I want where I want to insert selected psalm from the first document. I don't know how to start to keep it simple. I look to datatool but can a psalm be an entry ? Or Should a create a document for each psalm that will be called ? If yes, how can I do it quickly ? Can I call the psalm base on its title in the document containing all the psalm ?

Comment: It's unclear why you would need a database for this, unless you envision changing the order of the included psalms on demand, or including only some and not others. But even then, I don't think you need a database. Surely this is no different that any other large-ish document, where it makes sense to have each psalm as a separate file and then a master document that simply uses `\include` or `\input` to input them.

Comment: Of course you could make the master document simpler by naming each psalm file `psalm-x.tex` and then use a loop over `x`, but this is really a matter of whether you want a  3 line master document or a 150 line master document.  If you do need mix and match versions, then just keep a database of the filenames and use `datatool` or similar processing to do the different versions.

Comment: Thanks @AlanMunn yes I would like to change the order of the included psalms on demand etc. I was thinking about `\include` or `\input` but that mean I need to create a a document for each psalm that is to say 150 documents... Is there an easy way to create those documents ?

Comment: Since your source is in Word, it's probably fastest to simply cut and paste each into a new `.tex` document. This is something you do only once. https://xkcd.com/1205/ Since you're converting from Word, I would recommend using a unicode engine like XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. But I suspect there may be more issues lurking in the conversion than in the creating 150 files.

Comment: There’s [one of these for a different set of scriptures.](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/quran) You might look at its source.

Comment: Using [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/639525/118714) to "Create blocks of content to reference multiple times thorugh document" you can maintain all psalms within one single text-file, each psalm being a `\filesection` on its own which can be retrieved via `\inputfilesection`.

Comment: @UlrichDiez I am very insterested by your solution but I did not succeed to use it. Shall we load a specific package ?

Comment: @JBOP The example provided should compile as is and on my system does so. The phrase "I did not suceed to use it" does not provide much clue regarding what  problems/error-messages/unexpected behavior you encounter.

Comment: @JBOP If the LaTeX 2e-kernel in use is not up to date you may need to load the package xparse (`\usepackage{xparse`) in order to have things like `\NewDocumentCommand` work. (With up-to-date LaTeX 2e-kernel most of the facilities provided by xparse are included into the kernel.)

Comment: @JBOP If you maintain the content of all psalms within a single file which - in whatsoever way - is used for maintaining a database of psalms, the content of all psalms needs to be loaded/processed by LaTeX at least once although probably this is not needed as not all psalms are to occur within the document. In any case this might take time / memory during compilation. Probably an approach where each psalm is in a file on its own is better. If filenames are to difficult to remember, a system can be implemented for mapping from whatsoever easy-to-remember identification-phrases to filenames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to call the psalm I need from a master file composed of all the palms. So, in a .tex file, I have the "database" containing all the psalms. Each psalm is within a command which serve as a identifier. Here is an example:

```
\newcommand{\PsalmI}{%
Lorem ipsum...
}
\newcommand{\PsalmII}{%
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit...
}
```

In order to call the psalm, I need to call the macro `\PsalmI` for example.
However, as the psalm I called based on the content of another databased, I have created another command `\Psalmus` which name depends on the variable:

```
\newcommand{\Psalmus}[1]{\csname Psalm#1\endcsname}
```

To call the psalm, I just need to call it through the macro: `\Psalmus{II}` for example. This calls the macro `\PsalmII` and displays the second psalm.

This solution is based on Ulrike Fischer's solution to [this topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/433099/define-latex-command-in-which-argument-is-part-of-another-command).

Answer (score 1):

A database can contain whatever you want as data associated to a key. Even a longish text. Just need a database (-style package, you presumably just have a single key --psalm number/name-- and associated data --text--) package to handles that.

The Linux (BSD original, some work on porting to other platforms) `strfile(1)` utility (part of [fortune-mod](https://github.com/shlomif/fortune-mod) here) takes files made of paragraphs and creates a file indexed with the paragraphs for random access, you'd need to hack it to add a key. It could give some inspiration.

Or kludge up a script in some scripting language that reads text with some marker like `%% identifier` lines, and reads a file containing something like:

```
identifier1
Lorem ispum dolor sit amet, ...
%
identifier2
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit...
```

looks up the identifier and replaces by the following text.

Comment: I haven't try yet but according to `datatool` user guide, we cannot have paragraph break (and maybe no other command...)

Comment: @JBOP With datatool you actually cannot have the token `\par` because many of its macros are not defined in terms of `\long`. (An empty line in the .tex-input usually also yields the token `\par`.) But you can copy, e.g., via `\let\parcopy=\par` and use `\parcopy` where paragraph-breaks are needed. Or `\csname par\endcsname`. The actual problem is: database-entries consisting of a paragraph contain sequences of many characters. Long sequences of many characters cannot be written as a single line of .tex-input in case the database is written to external file.

Answer (score 0):

In case with "tex document" a document for compiling with LaTeX 2ε is meant:

As a variant of [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/628018/118714) to [Using Latex code chunks as library - For reusing latex elements such as figures in multiple representations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/627989/118714) I can offer an interface where files with specifiable sections are of pattern

```
\filesection{⟨name of file-section⟩}
⟨code⟩
\endfilesection
%-------------------------------------------------------------
\filesection{⟨name of file-section⟩}
⟨code⟩
\endfilesection
%-------------------------------------------------------------
\filesection{⟨name of file-section⟩}
⟨code⟩
\endfilesection
%-------------------------------------------------------------
\endinput
```

You input these files with the command

```
\inputfilesection{⟨name of file⟩}{⟨name of file-section⟩}
```

The *⟨code⟩* of a file-section will be executed only if both the `\inputfilesection`-command and the `\filesection`-comand have the same *⟨name of file-section⟩*-argument.

In this case *⟨code⟩* will be read under verbatim-catcode-régime. Then the result is passed to `\scantokens` for re-tokenization and normal processing.

Several `\filesection`s can have the same *⟨name of file-section⟩*. In this case all file-sections of the name in question occurring in the file are delivered by `\inputfilesection`.

**CAVEATS I AM AWARE OF:**

!!!Don't do `\inputfilesection` inside files that are called by `\inputfilesection`!!!

Here is a minimal working example tailored to your need of typesetting psalms.
On my system the example compiles without problems.
If you encounter problems/error-messages/undesired behavior, let me know about it.

```latex
%=================================================================================
%
% Via filecontents*-environment let's create an external text file
% `PsalmDatabase.tex` which contains \filesection-commands for denoting single
% portions of the file which can be imported into a document via the command
% \inputfilesection which in turn is defined in the code below.
%
% The external text file PsalmDatabase.tex is created on the fly via
% filecontents*- environment so that it is ensured that it is available when this
% example is compiled. Instead of doing it this way, you can also maintain
% PsalmDatabase.tex  as a separate file which is stored in a place where it can
% be foud by LaTeX. 
%
%\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{PsalmDatabase.tex}
\begin{filecontents*}{PsalmDatabase.tex}
\filesection{Psalm 1}
[This is whatsoever TeX-code for typesetting psalm 1.]
\section*{Psalm 1}
\begin{verbatim*}
Some verbatim material in 
code for typesetting psalm 1.
\end{verbatim*}
\endfilesection
%-------------------------------------------------------------
\filesection{Psalm 2}
[This is whatsoever TeX-code for typesetting psalm 2.]
\section*{Psalm 2}
This is psalm 2.

This is psalm 2.
\endfilesection
%-------------------------------------------------------------
\filesection{Psalm 3}
[This is whatsoever TeX-code for typesetting psalm 2.]
\section*{Psalm 3}
This is the third psalm.
\begin{verbatim*}
Some verbatim material
in code for typesetting psalm 3.
\end{verbatim*}
\endfilesection
%-------------------------------------------------------------
\endinput
\end{filecontents*}

%=================================================================================
%
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{NewDocumentCommand}{\RequirePackage{xparse}}{}%
%///// begin of code that could go into a package / .sty-file//////////////////
\NewDocumentCommand\inputfilesection{mm}{%
  \def\@stringincommand{#2}%
  \input{#1}%
}%
\newcommand\@stringincommand{}%
\newcommand\@stringinfile{}%
\NewDocumentCommand\filesection{m}{%
  \begingroup
  \let\do\@makeother\dospecials
  \do\^^I%
  \do\^^M%
  \@filesection{#1}%
}%
\begingroup
\newcommand\@filesection[2]{%
  \endgroup
  \def\@filesection##1##2#1{%
     \def\@stringinfile{##1}%
     \expandafter\endgroup
     \ifx\@stringinfile\@stringincommand\expandafter\@firstofone\else\expandafter\@gobble\fi
     {%
       \begingroup
       \newlinechar=\endlinechar
       \scantokens\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
       \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
       \UD@RemoveLeadingNTrailingCarriageReturn{##2}#2}%
     }\ignorespaces
  }%
}%
\@firstofone{%
  \let\do\@makeother\dospecials
  \catcode`\{=1 %
  \catcode`\}=2 %
  \@filesection
}{\endfilesection}{\ignorespaces%}%
%=================================================================================
% Begin of code for removing one leading and one trailing explicit
% <carriage-return>-character-token of catcode 12(other) from _verbatimized_ 
% argument
%=================================================================================
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\@secondoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begingroup
\@makeother\^^M%
\@firstofone{%
  \endgroup%
  %%=============================================================================
  %% Check whether_verbatimized_ argument has a leading explicit 
  %% <carriage-return>-character-token of catcode 12(other):
  %%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  %% \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingCarriageReturn{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
  %%                                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case
  %%                                       <argument which is to be checked>'s
  %%                                       1st token is an explicit <carriage-
  %%                                       return>-character-token of 
  %%                                       catcode 12(other)>}%
  %%                                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case
  %%                                       <argument which is to be checked>'s
  %%                                       1st token is not an explicit
  %%                                       <carriage-return>-character-token of 
  %%                                       catcode 12(other)>}%
  \newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingCarriageReturn[1]{%
    \UD@@CheckWhetherLeadingCarriageReturn\UD@SelDom#1\UD@SelDom^^M\UD@@SelDom%
  }%
  \@ifdefinable\UD@@CheckWhetherLeadingCarriageReturn{%
    \long\def\UD@@CheckWhetherLeadingCarriageReturn#1\UD@SelDom^^M#2\UD@@SelDom{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#2}{\@secondoftwo}{\@firstoftwo}%
    }%
  }%
  %%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  %% Check whether_verbatimized_ argument having a leading explicit <carriage-
  %% return>-character-token of catcode 12(other) consists only of such tokens:
  %%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  %% \UD@CheckWhetherOnlyCarriageReturn{<Argument which is to be checked and 
  %%                                    which is known to have a leading explicit
  %%                                    <carriage-return>-character-token of
  %%                                    catcode 12(other)>}%
  %%                                   {<Tokens to be delivered in case <argument
  %%                                    which is to be checked> consists only
  %%                                    of explicit <carriage-return>-character-
  %%                                    tokens of catcode 12(other)>}%
  %%                                   {<Tokens to be delivered in case <argument
  %%                                    which is to be checked> does not consist
  %%                                    only of explicit <carriage-return>-
  %%                                    character-tokens of catcode 12(other)>}%
  \newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherOnlyCarriageReturn[1]{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingCarriageReturn{#1}{%
      \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherOnlyCarriageReturn%
      \expandafter{\UD@@TrimLeadingCarriageReturn#1}%
    }{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{\@firstoftwo}{\@secondoftwo}%
    }%
  }%
  %%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  %% Remove one leading explicit <carriage-return>-character-token of 
  %% catcode 12(other) from _verbatimized_ argument:
  %%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \@ifdefinable\UD@@TrimLeadingCarriageReturn{%
    \long\def\UD@@TrimLeadingCarriageReturn^^M{}%
  }%
  %%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  %% Check whether_verbatimized_ argument has a trailing explicit 
  %% <carriage-return>-character-token of catcode 12(other):
  %%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  %% \UD@CheckWhetherTrailingCarriageReturn{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
  %%                                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case
  %%                                       <argument which is to be checked>'s
  %%                                       last token is an explicit <carriage-
  %%                                       return>-character-token of 
  %%                                       catcode 12(other)>}%
  %%                                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case
  %%                                       <argument which is to be checked>'s
  %%                                       last token is not an explicit
  %%                                       <carriage-return>-character-token of 
  %%                                       catcode 12(other)>}%
  \newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherTrailingCarriageReturn[1]{%
    \UD@@CheckWhetherTrailingCarriageReturn#1\UD@SelDom^^M\UD@SelDom\UD@@SelDom%
  }%
  \@ifdefinable\UD@@CheckWhetherTrailingCarriageReturn{%
    \long\def\UD@@CheckWhetherTrailingCarriageReturn#1^^M\UD@SelDom#2\UD@@SelDom{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#2}{\@secondoftwo}{\@firstoftwo}%
    }%
  }%
  %%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  %% Remove one trailing explicit <carriage-return>-character-token of 
  %% catcode 12(other) from _verbatimized_ argument:
  %%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \newcommand\UD@TrimTrailingCarriageReturn[1]{%
     \UD@@TrimTrailingCarriageReturn#1\UD@SelDom%
  }%
  \@ifdefinable\UD@@TrimTrailingCarriageReturn{%
    \long\def\UD@@TrimTrailingCarriageReturn#1^^M\UD@SelDom{#1}%
  }%
  %%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  %% Remove one leading and one trailing explicit <carriage-return>-character-
  %% token of catcode 12(other) from _verbatimized_ argument if present.
  %% In the edge case of the _verbatimized_ argument consisting only of explicit
  %% <carriage-return>-character-tokens of catcode 12(other) remove only one of 
  %% them.
  %% Due to \romannumeral-expansion the result is delivered in 2 expansion-steps:
  %%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \newcommand\UD@RemoveLeadingNTrailingCarriageReturn[1]{%
    \romannumeral%
    \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingCarriageReturn{#1}{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherTrailingCarriageReturn{#1}{%
         \UD@CheckWhetherOnlyCarriageReturn{#1}{%
           \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@@TrimLeadingCarriageReturn#1%
         }{%
           \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter%
           \expandafter\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\expandafter%
           \UD@TrimTrailingCarriageReturn\expandafter{\UD@@TrimLeadingCarriageReturn#1}%
         }%
      }{%
        \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@@TrimLeadingCarriageReturn#1%
      }%
    }{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherTrailingCarriageReturn{#1}{%
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral%
        \UD@TrimTrailingCarriageReturn{#1}%
      }{\UD@stopromannumeral#1}%
    }%
  }%
}%
%================================================================================
% End of code for removing one leading and one trailing explicit
% <carriage-return>-character-token of catcode 12(other) from _verbatimized_ 
% argument
%================================================================================
%///// end of code that could go into a package / .sty-file////////////////////
\makeatother

%================================================================================
% A document where the command \inputfilesection, whose definition forms the code 
% that could go into a package / .sty-file, is used for inputting sections/
% portions of the external file  `PsalmDatabase.tex`
% 

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent\textbf{Here comes Psalm 1:}\bigskip

\inputfilesection{PsalmDatabase.tex}{Psalm 1}

\bigskip\hrule\bigskip\noindent\textbf{That is Psalm 2:}\bigskip

\inputfilesection{PsalmDatabase.tex}{Psalm 2}

\bigskip\hrule\bigskip\noindent\textbf{Now let's have Psalm 3:}\bigskip

\inputfilesection{PsalmDatabase.tex}{Psalm 3}

\bigskip\hrule\bigskip\noindent\textbf{Here comes Psalm 1 again:}\bigskip

\inputfilesection{PsalmDatabase.tex}{Psalm 1}

\bigskip\hrule\bigskip\noindent\textbf{That is Psalm 2 again:}\bigskip

\inputfilesection{PsalmDatabase.tex}{Psalm 2}

\bigskip\hrule\bigskip\noindent\textbf{Now let's have Psalm 3 again:}\bigskip

\inputfilesection{PsalmDatabase.tex}{Psalm 3}

\end{document}
```

pdf-output looks like this:

[image]

If you wish to split this into several files, you can, e.g., do something like  this:

File `PsalmDatabase.tex`:

```latex
\filesection{Psalm 1}
[This is whatsoever TeX-code for typesetting psalm 1.]
\section*{Psalm 1}
\begin{verbatim*}
Some verbatim material in 
code for typesetting psalm 1.
\end{verbatim*}
\endfilesection
%-------------------------------------------------------------
\filesection{Psalm 2}
[This is whatsoever TeX-code for typesetting psalm 2.]
\section*{Psalm 2}
This is psalm 2.

This is psalm 2.
\endfilesection
%-------------------------------------------------------------
\filesection{Psalm 3}
[This is whatsoever TeX-code for typesetting psalm 2.]
\section*{Psalm 3}
This is the third psalm.
\begin{verbatim*}
Some verbatim material
in code for typesetting psalm 3.
\end{verbatim*}
\endfilesection
%-------------------------------------------------------------
\endinput
```

File `inputfilesections.sty`:

```latex
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{inputfilesections}[2022/07/18 v0.01 import portions of .tex-files]
\@ifundefined{NewDocumentCommand}{\RequirePackage{xparse}}{}%
\NewDocumentCommand\inputfilesection{mm}{%
  \def\@stringincommand{#2}%
  \input{#1}%
}%
\newcommand\@stringincommand{}%
\newcommand\@stringinfile{}%
\NewDocumentCommand\filesection{m}{%
  \begingroup
  \let\do\@makeother\dospecials
  \do\^^I%
  \do\^^M%
  \@filesection{#1}%
}%
\begingroup
\newcommand\@filesection[2]{%
  \endgroup
  \def\@filesection##1##2#1{%
     \def\@stringinfile{##1}%
     \expandafter\endgroup
     \ifx\@stringinfile\@stringincommand\expandafter\@firstofone\else\expandafter\@gobble\fi
     {%
       \begingroup
       \newlinechar=\endlinechar
       \scantokens\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
       \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
       \UD@RemoveLeadingNTrailingCarriageReturn{##2}#2}%
     }\ignorespaces
  }%
}%
\@firstofone{%
  \let\do\@makeother\dospecials
  \catcode`\{=1 %
  \catcode`\}=2 %
  \@filesection
}{\endfilesection}{\ignorespaces%}%
%=================================================================================
% Begin of code for removing one leading and one trailing explicit
% <carriage-return>-character-token of catcode 12(other) from _verbatimized_ 
% argument
%=================================================================================
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\@secondoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begingroup
\@makeother\^^M%
\@firstofone{%
  \endgroup%
  %%=============================================================================
  %% Check whether_verbatimized_ argument has a leading explicit 
  %% <carriage-return>-character-token of catcode 12(other):
  %%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  %% \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingCarriageReturn{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
  %%                                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case
  %%                                       <argument which is to be checked>'s
  %%                                       1st token is an explicit <carriage-
  %%                                       return>-character-token of 
  %%                                       catcode 12(other)>}%
  %%                                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case
  %%                                       <argument which is to be checked>'s
  %%                                       1st token is not an explicit
  %%                                       <carriage-return>-character-token of 
  %%                                       catcode 12(other)>}%
  \newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingCarriageReturn[1]{%
    \UD@@CheckWhetherLeadingCarriageReturn\UD@SelDom#1\UD@SelDom^^M\UD@@SelDom%
  }%
  \@ifdefinable\UD@@CheckWhetherLeadingCarriageReturn{%
    \long\def\UD@@CheckWhetherLeadingCarriageReturn#1\UD@SelDom^^M#2\UD@@SelDom{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#2}{\@secondoftwo}{\@firstoftwo}%
    }%
  }%
  %%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  %% Check whether_verbatimized_ argument having a leading explicit <carriage-
  %% return>-character-token of catcode 12(other) consists only of such tokens:
  %%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  %% \UD@CheckWhetherOnlyCarriageReturn{<Argument which is to be checked and 
  %%                                    which is known to have a leading explicit
  %%                                    <carriage-return>-character-token of
  %%                                    catcode 12(other)>}%
  %%                                   {<Tokens to be delivered in case <argument
  %%                                    which is to be checked> consists only
  %%                                    of explicit <carriage-return>-character-
  %%                                    tokens of catcode 12(other)>}%
  %%                                   {<Tokens to be delivered in case <argument
  %%                                    which is to be checked> does not consist
  %%                                    only of explicit <carriage-return>-
  %%                                    character-tokens of catcode 12(other)>}%
  \newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherOnlyCarriageReturn[1]{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingCarriageReturn{#1}{%
      \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherOnlyCarriageReturn%
      \expandafter{\UD@@TrimLeadingCarriageReturn#1}%
    }{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{\@firstoftwo}{\@secondoftwo}%
    }%
  }%
  %%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  %% Remove one leading explicit <carriage-return>-character-token of 
  %% catcode 12(other) from _verbatimized_ argument:
  %%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \@ifdefinable\UD@@TrimLeadingCarriageReturn{%
    \long\def\UD@@TrimLeadingCarriageReturn^^M{}%
  }%
  %%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  %% Check whether_verbatimized_ argument has a trailing explicit 
  %% <carriage-return>-character-token of catcode 12(other):
  %%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  %% \UD@CheckWhetherTrailingCarriageReturn{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
  %%                                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case
  %%                                       <argument which is to be checked>'s
  %%                                       last token is an explicit <carriage-
  %%                                       return>-character-token of 
  %%                                       catcode 12(other)>}%
  %%                                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case
  %%                                       <argument which is to be checked>'s
  %%                                       last token is not an explicit
  %%                                       <carriage-return>-character-token of 
  %%                                       catcode 12(other)>}%
  \newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherTrailingCarriageReturn[1]{%
    \UD@@CheckWhetherTrailingCarriageReturn#1\UD@SelDom^^M\UD@SelDom\UD@@SelDom%
  }%
  \@ifdefinable\UD@@CheckWhetherTrailingCarriageReturn{%
    \long\def\UD@@CheckWhetherTrailingCarriageReturn#1^^M\UD@SelDom#2\UD@@SelDom{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#2}{\@secondoftwo}{\@firstoftwo}%
    }%
  }%
  %%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  %% Remove one trailing explicit <carriage-return>-character-token of 
  %% catcode 12(other) from _verbatimized_ argument:
  %%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \newcommand\UD@TrimTrailingCarriageReturn[1]{%
     \UD@@TrimTrailingCarriageReturn#1\UD@SelDom%
  }%
  \@ifdefinable\UD@@TrimTrailingCarriageReturn{%
    \long\def\UD@@TrimTrailingCarriageReturn#1^^M\UD@SelDom{#1}%
  }%
  %%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  %% Remove one leading and one trailing explicit <carriage-return>-character-
  %% token of catcode 12(other) from _verbatimized_ argument if present.
  %% In the edge case of the _verbatimized_ argument consisting only of explicit
  %% <carriage-return>-character-tokens of catcode 12(other) remove only one of 
  %% them.
  %% Due to \romannumeral-expansion the result is delivered in 2 expansion-steps:
  %%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \newcommand\UD@RemoveLeadingNTrailingCarriageReturn[1]{%
    \romannumeral%
    \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingCarriageReturn{#1}{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherTrailingCarriageReturn{#1}{%
         \UD@CheckWhetherOnlyCarriageReturn{#1}{%
           \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@@TrimLeadingCarriageReturn#1%
         }{%
           \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter%
           \expandafter\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\expandafter%
           \UD@TrimTrailingCarriageReturn\expandafter{\UD@@TrimLeadingCarriageReturn#1}%
         }%
      }{%
        \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@@TrimLeadingCarriageReturn#1%
      }%
    }{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherTrailingCarriageReturn{#1}{%
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral%
        \UD@TrimTrailingCarriageReturn{#1}%
      }{\UD@stopromannumeral#1}%
    }%
  }%
}%
%================================================================================
% End of code for removing one leading and one trailing explicit
% <carriage-return>-character-token of catcode 12(other) from _verbatimized_ 
% argument
\endinput
```

File `document.tex`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{inputfilesections}

\begin{document}

\noindent\textbf{Here comes Psalm 1:}\bigskip

\inputfilesection{PsalmDatabase.tex}{Psalm 1}

\bigskip\hrule\bigskip\noindent\textbf{That is Psalm 2:}\bigskip

\inputfilesection{PsalmDatabase.tex}{Psalm 2}

\bigskip\hrule\bigskip\noindent\textbf{Now let's have Psalm 3:}\bigskip

\inputfilesection{PsalmDatabase.tex}{Psalm 3}

\bigskip\hrule\bigskip\noindent\textbf{Here comes Psalm 1 again:}\bigskip

\inputfilesection{PsalmDatabase.tex}{Psalm 1}

\bigskip\hrule\bigskip\noindent\textbf{That is Psalm 2 again:}\bigskip

\inputfilesection{PsalmDatabase.tex}{Psalm 2}

\bigskip\hrule\bigskip\noindent\textbf{Now let's have Psalm 3 again:}\bigskip

\inputfilesection{PsalmDatabase.tex}{Psalm 3}

\end{document}
```

If some of the code in your file-sections requires some package to be loaded in the document-preamble, the file `PsalmDatabase.tex` can contain a file-section "RequiredPackages" which in turn contains the corresponding `\RequirePackage`- or `\usepackage`-commands.  This way, if some of the code in your filesections needs some packages, you don't need to remember loading these package. Instead, in the preamble of your document just do `\inputfilesection{PsalmDatabase.tex}{RequiredPackages}`.