# Using Latex code chunks as library - For reusing latex elements such as figures in multiple representations

Tags: include, trees, includegraphics, variable

In object programming languages often structs exist which help you to reuse code twice or often, but writing that code only one time.

A convenient way to write Latex code if the author does not want to dive too deep into Latex is to simply use a template.

The use case here is that the author wants to have shared components to include which are template independent. For sections and subsection I think this is quite common. But the author wants to share the code for an element such as code for a figure and caption into for example a book template and a presentation template.

A file **exampleFigure.tex** has content

```
      \begin{figure}[h!]
        \includegraphics[width=0.6\paperwidth]{examplePath/exampleFigure.png}
        \caption{Example Section.}
      \end{figure}
```

and be included in **exampleBookSection.tex**

```
       The example BlaBla shows the ... and we can see in figure:

       \include{exampleFigure}

       but on the other hand ...
```

as well as in **examplePresentationSlide.tex**

```
    \begin{frame}{ExampleSlide}
       \framesubtitle{Random Bla}%
       \include{exampleFigure}
    \end{frame}
```

The named use case already gets pretty much more complex if we want to replace in **exampleFigure.tex** *[width=0.6\paperwidth]* to *[width=0.8\paperwidth]* in for example the include in **examplePresentationSlide.tex**. In programming we can simply reuse code fragments by having variables as parameters.

In every example I found for **include** mechanism a **child.tex** is included only one time in a **parent.tex**. Those examples have a tree structure. My use case allows **child.tex** included by two parents **parent1.tex** and **parent2.tex**. I want even multiple roots (template files).

- Is such a structure maintainable or not?
- Do helpful latex IDE's exist if it is maintainable?
- Is there a helpful guide to follow here for recommendations how to solve things such as the parameterization problem named above?

How to solve the parameterization question?

Comment: This is quite confusing... anyway, it looks like that you just want to define a macro. (go read up and come back if you have more questions.)

Comment: @moewe Actually, include does more (own aux file) and input would be what just takes the content. Imo, include is wrong in thas case.

Comment: @TeXnician Ach! I confused `\include` and `\input` again. Thanks for pointing that out. I'll delete the comments (too late to edit them now :-().

Answer (score 3):

"Libraries" in LaTex are called packages and included via

```
\usepackage{mystuff}
```

With the code accessed by, for example `\myfig{fig:zz}{myfigure}{my caption}`

where, in this case `mystuff.sty` should have

```
\newcommand\myfig[4][htp]{%
\begin{figure}[#1]%
\includegraphics[width=0.6\paperwidth]{#3}%
\caption{#4\label{#2}}%
\end{figure}}
```

note I made the positional argument optional so you can go `\myfig[!ht]` when needed. You shouldn't routinely add `!` as it is for exceptional use to over-ride the document wide settings, it doesn't make sense to set document wide settings then always ignore them. Also using `h` on its own is usually an error and LaTeX will warn about it and change it, so `htp` is a better default.

Answer (score 1):

Some valiant attempts have been made to do this (cf. [Passing parameters to \input{text} (included text file)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338029/passing-parameters-to-inputtext-included-text-file) as a starting point), but I find it's usually not worth it.

What you can do, however, is have variables/macros in the parent document (even change them on the fly, as it were) and reference that in the child.

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
        \includegraphics[width=\mywidth]{\myfigure}
        \caption{\mycaption}
\end{figure}
```

… in conjunction with, say,

```
\def\mywidth{.6\paperwidth}
\def\myfigure{examplePath/exampleFigure} % usually best to omit the .png etc suffix
\def\mycaption{This is a caption!}
\input{exampleFigure.tex}

% using the same width, so no need to redefine
\def\myfigure{examplePath/exampleFigure2}
\def\mycaption{Another caption!}
\input{exampleFigure.tex}
```

As you can see, you'd have to redefine your variables before `\input`ing your snippet, as needed. That said, I am a copy & paste guy myself when it comes to these things. The most tedious part, in my book, is the preamble anyway (don't get me started on font setup), and I certainly reuse those.

Comment: I stand corrected. I take my hat off to your proofreading skills!

Answer (score 1):

I can offer an interface where template-files are of pattern

```
\filesection{⟨name of section⟩}{⟨replacement for the token \default⟩}
⟨code⟩
\endfilesection
%-------------------------------------------------------------
\filesection{⟨name of section⟩}{⟨replacement for the token \default⟩}
⟨code⟩
\endfilesection
%-------------------------------------------------------------
\filesection{⟨name of section⟩}{⟨replacement for the token \default⟩}
⟨code⟩
\endfilesection
%-------------------------------------------------------------
\endinput
```

You input the template-files with the command

```
\inputfilesection{⟨name of template-file⟩}%
                 {⟨name of section⟩}%
                 [⟨replacement for the token \default⟩]
```

The *⟨code⟩* of a file-section will be executed only if both the `\inputfilesection`-command and the `\filesection`-comand have the same *⟨name of section⟩*-argument.

In this case *⟨code⟩* will be read under verbatim-catcode-régime and the sequence `\default` will be replaced:
If the `\inputfilesection`-command specifies a *⟨replacement for the token `\default`⟩*-argument, then the replacement will come from that argument.
Otherwise the replacement will come from the `\filesection`-command's *⟨replacement for the token `\default`⟩*-argument.

The result is passed to `\scantokens` for re-tokenization and normal processing.

Several `\filesection`s can have the same *⟨name of section⟩*. In this case all file-sections of the name in question occurring in the template-file are delivered by `\inputfilesection`. In this case if the `\inputfilesection`-provides a *⟨replacement for the token `\default`⟩*-argument, this argument will be used as replacement for the token `\default` with all file-sections delivered.

**CAVEATS I AM AWARE OF:**

!!!Don't do `\inputfilesection` inside files that are called by `\inputfilesection`!!!

!!!`\inputfilesection` attempts to read the *⟨replacement for the token `\default`⟩*-argument under verbatim-catcode-régime. Therefore `\inputfilesection` should not be used inside arguments of other macros and the like.!!!

```latex
%
% A exemplary template-file:
%
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{MyTemplates.tex}
%\begin{filecontents*}{MyTemplates.tex}
\filesection{example-image-a}{width=0.6\textwidth}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[\default]{example-image-a}
\caption{Example Section.}
\end{figure}
\endfilesection
%-------------------------------------------------------------
\filesection{example-image-b}{width=0.6\textwidth}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[\default]{example-image-b}
\caption{Example Section.}
\end{figure}
\endfilesection
%-------------------------------------------------------------
\filesection{example-image-c}{width=0.6\textwidth}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[\default]{example-image-c}
\caption{Example Section.}
\end{figure}
%\show\defaultABC %% This yields \show\defaultABC 
                  % , resulting in > \defaultABC=undefined.
                  % This is a test to make sure that replacing
                  % is not done if the sequence \default is
                  % trailed by a character whose catcode at the
                  % time of replacing is 11.
\endfilesection
%-------------------------------------------------------------
\endinput
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
%///// start of code that could go into a package / .sty-file//////////////////
\newcommand\UD@ifnextcharspace[3]{%
  \let\reserved@d= #1%
  \edef\reserved@a{\unexpanded{#2}}%
  \edef\reserved@b{\unexpanded{#3}}%
  \futurelet\@let@token\UD@ifnch
}%
\newcommand\UD@ifnch{%
  \ifx\@let@token\reserved@d\expandafter\reserved@a\else\expandafter\reserved@b\fi
}%

\NewDocumentCommand\inputfilesection{mm}{%
  % Use \UD@ifnextcharspace for ensuring the next token is read under 
  % normal catcode-régime:
  \begingroup
  \UD@ifnextcharspace[{%
    \let\do\@makeother\dospecials
    \do\^^I%
    \do\^^M%
    \@inputfilesection{#1}{#2}%
  }{%
    \let\do\@makeother\dospecials
    \do\^^I%
    \do\^^M%
    \@inputfilesection{#1}{#2}%
  }%
}%
\NewDocumentCommand\@inputfilesection{mm!o}{%
  \endgroup
  \def\@stringincommand{#2}%
  \IfNoValueF{#3}{\def\default{#3}}%
  \input{#1}%
  \global\let\default\UndeFinEd
}%
\newcommand\@stringincommand{}%
\newcommand\@stringinfile{}%
\NewDocumentCommand\filesection{m}{%
  \begingroup\@makeother\^^I\relax
  \@filesection{#1}%
}%
\NewDocumentCommand\@filesection{mv}{%
  \endgroup
  \begingroup
  \let\do\@makeother\dospecials
  \do\^^I%
  \do\^^M%
  \@@filesection{#1}{#2}%
}%
\begingroup
\newcommand\@@filesection[3]{%
  \endgroup
  \def\@@filesection##1##2##3#1{%
     \def\@stringinfile{##1}%
     \expandafter\endgroup
     \ifx\@stringinfile\@stringincommand\expandafter\@firstofone\else\expandafter\@gobble\fi
     {%
       \begingroup
       \@ifundefined{default}{\def\default{##2}}{}%
       \newlinechar=\endlinechar
       \scantokens
       \expandafter\expandafter
       \expandafter\expandafter
       \expandafter\expandafter
       \expandafter{\expandafter\UD@Replacedefault\expandafter{\default}{##3}{#3}#2}%
     }\ignorespaces
  }%
}%
\@firstofone{%
  \let\do\@makeother\dospecials
  \do\^^I%
  \catcode`\{=1 %
  \catcode`\}=2 %
  \@@filesection
}{\endfilesection}{%}{\endgroup\ignorespaces }%
%
%
%%/////////// code for \UD@Replacedefault /////////////////////////////////////
%%=============================================================================
%% PARAPHERNALIA:
%% \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo, \UD@PassFirstToSecond, \UD@Exchange,
%% \UD@stopromannumeral, \UD@CheckWhetherNull, \UD@ExtractFirstArg
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwobraced[2]{{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Extract first inner undelimited argument:
%%.............................................................................
%%   \UD@ExtractFirstArg{ABCDE} yields  {A}
%%
%%   \UD@ExtractFirstArg{{AB}CDE} yields  {{AB}}
%%
%% Due to \romannumeral-expansion the result is delivered after two 
%% expansion-steps/after "hitting" \UD@ExtractFirstArg with \expandafter
%% twice.
%%
%% \UD@ExtractFirstArg's argument must not be blank.
%% This case can be cranked out via \UD@CheckWhetherBlank before calling
%% \UD@ExtractFirstArg.
%%
%% Use frozen-\relax as delimiter for speeding things up.
%% Frozen-\relax is chosen because David Carlisle pointed out in
%% <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578877>
%% that frozen-\relax cannot be (re)defined in terms of \outer and cannot be
%% affected by \uppercase/\lowercase.
%%
%% \UD@ExtractFirstArg's argument may contain frozen-\relax:
%% The only effect is that internally more iterations are needed for
%% obtaining the result.
%%.............................................................................
\@ifdefinable\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@Exchange
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\ifnum0=0\fi}%
  {\long\def\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax#1#2}{{#1}}%
}%
\expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter
  \UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\romannumeral
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@Exchange
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\ifnum0=0\fi}{\UD@stopromannumeral#1}%
  }{%
    \UD@stopromannumeral\romannumeral\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop
  }%
}{%
  \newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstArg[1]%
}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  {\UD@stopromannumeral#1}%
  {\expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax#1}}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% \UD@ForkDefaultPhrase{<tokens to check>}
%%                      {<tokens in case <tokens to check> equal \default>}
%%                      {<tokens in case <tokens to check> are sub-phrase of \default>}
%%                      {<tokens in other cases>}
%%=============================================================================
\@ifdefinable\UD@gobbletoexclam{\long\def\UD@gobbletoexclam#1!{}}%
\begingroup
\newcommand\UD@ForkDefaultPhrase[8]{%
  \endgroup
  \newcommand\UD@ForkDefaultPhrase[1]{%
    \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@gobbletoexclam##1!}%
    {%
      \UD@DefaultPhraseFork
      !##1!#2!#3!#4!#5!#6!#7!#8!{\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\UD@firstoftwo{}}%
      !#1!##1!#3!#4!#5!#6!#7!#8!{\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\UD@firstoftwo{}}%
      !#1!#2!##1!#4!#5!#6!#7!#8!{\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\UD@firstoftwo{}}%
      !#1!#2!#3!##1!#5!#6!#7!#8!{\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\UD@firstoftwo{}}%
      !#1!#2!#3!#4!##1!#6!#7!#8!{\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\UD@firstoftwo{}}%
      !#1!#2!#3!#4!#5!##1!#7!#8!{\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\UD@firstoftwo{}}%
      !#1!#2!#3!#4!#5!#6!##1!#8!{\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\UD@firstoftwo{}}%
      !#1!#2!#3!#4!#5!#6!#7!##1!{\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\UD@firstoftwobraced}%
      !#1!#2!#3!#4!#5!#6!#7!#8!{\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\UD@firstoftwo{}}%
      !!!!%
    }{\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\UD@firstoftwo{}}%
  }%
  \@ifdefinable\UD@DefaultPhraseFork{%
    \long\def\UD@DefaultPhraseFork##1!#1!#2!#3!#4!#5!#6!#7!#8!##2##3!!!!{##2}%
  }%
}%
\@firstofone{%
  \let\do\@makeother\dospecials
  \do\^^I
  \catcode`\{=1 %
  \catcode`\}=2 %
  \UD@ForkDefaultPhrase
}{\}{\d}{\de}{\def}{\defa}{\defau}{\defaul}{\default}%
%%=============================================================================
%% \UD@Replacedefault{<Replacement>}%
%%                   {<List of character-tokens where the sequence
%%                     \default is to be replaced>}%
%%                   {<tokens to prepend to result>}%
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@Replacedefault[3]{%
  % #1 - <Replacement>
  % #2 - <List where the token \default is to be replaced>
  % #3 - <tokens to prepend to result>
  \romannumeral\UD@Replacedefaultloop{}{}{\UD@secondoftwo}{#2}{#3}{#1}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@Replacedefaultloop[6]{%
   % #1 - <Result collected so far>
   % #2 - <sub-phrase of \default collected so far>
   % #3 - <flag for checking catcode of subsequent character if phrase \default is collected>
   % #4 - <List of character-tokens>
   % #5 - <tokens to prepend to result>
   % #6 - <Replacement>
   \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#4}{%
     \UD@ForkDefaultPhrase{#2}\UD@firstoftwo\UD@secondoftwo\UD@secondoftwo
                          {\UD@stopromannumeral#5#1#6}{\UD@stopromannumeral#5#1#2}%
   }{%
      \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#4}{%
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\UD@ExtractFirstArg{#4}{%
          \UD@defaultreplace{#5}{#6}{#1}{#2}{#3}%
        }%
      }%
   }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@defaultreplace[7]{%
  % #1 - <tokens to prepend to result>
  % #2 - <Replacement>
  % #3 - <Result collected so far>
  % #4 - <sub-phrase of \default collected so far>
  % #5 - <flag for checking catcode of subsequent character if phrase \default is collected>
  % #6 - <Character in this iteration>
  % #7 - <Remaining List of character-tokens>
  \expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\UD@Replacedefaultloop\romannumeral
    #5{%
      \ifnum\the\catcode\expandafter`\csname\string#6\endcsname=11 %
      \expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\fi
      {\UD@stopromannumeral{#3#4}}{\UD@stopromannumeral{#3#2}}{}{\UD@secondoftwo}{#6#7}%
    }{%
      \UD@ForkDefaultPhrase{#4#6}%
                           {\UD@stopromannumeral{#3}{#4#6}{\UD@firstoftwo}}%
                           {\UD@stopromannumeral{#3}{#4#6}{\UD@secondoftwo}}%
                           {\UD@stopromannumeral{#3#4#6}{}{\UD@secondoftwo}}%
                           {#7}%
    }%
  }{}{#1}{#2}%
}%
%%/////////// end of code for \UD@Replacedefault //////////////////////////////
%///// end of code that could go into a package / .sty-file////////////////////
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\inputfilesection{MyTemplates.tex}{example-image-a}

\inputfilesection{MyTemplates.tex}{example-image-b}

\inputfilesection{MyTemplates.tex}{example-image-c}

\inputfilesection{MyTemplates.tex}{example-image-a}[width=.3\textwidth]

\inputfilesection{MyTemplates.tex}{example-image-b}[width=.3\textwidth]

\inputfilesection{MyTemplates.tex}{example-image-c}[width=.3\textwidth]

\end{document}
```

[image]